# How to display image using xslt and xml?

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt

I have been trying to display image for quite sometimes now and some of the solutions in this website does not work for me...

This is my xslt code

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <div class="main">
      <h2>Product Catalogue</h2>
      <xsl:for-each select="productdetails/product">
        <div class="box">
          <img src="<xsl:value-of select="product_image"/>"> </img>
          <xsl:value-of select="format-number(product_Price,'0.00')" />

          <h3>
            <xsl:value-of select="product_Name"/>
          </h3>

          RM<xsl:value-of select="format-number(product_Price,'0.00')" />
          <br/>

          <p style="font-size:9pt; font-style: italic;">
            <xsl:value-of select="product_description"/>
          </p>

          <br/>

          <a href="#" runat="server" onserverclick="Cart">Add to Cart </a>

        </div>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
    </xsl:template>
```

Just so you know product_image in the xml is already the imagepath thats why I did not need to write the path in the xslt code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XML, a tag cannot contain another tag - so this is invalid code:

```
<img src="<xsl:value-of select="product_image"/>"> </img>
```

Use either:

```
<img>
    <xsl:attribute name="src">
        <xsl:value-of select="product_image"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</img>
```

or:

```
<img src="{product_image}"/>
```

To understand the 2nd syntax, read about [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#attribute-value-templates).

Comment: yea made sense... i used the first solution and it seems to work but it did not seem to load the image tho, it just shows an icon. i checked the image and nothing is wrong with it

Comment: I don't see your input and I don't know what's in the `product_image` element - or even if the path to`product_image` is correct. Check the code produced by the XSL transformation and see if the `src` attribute contains a valid path.

Comment: in product_image is example "~/Image/Cocktail.png" and the rest load nicely except product_image

Comment: There are two questions here: (1) Does your XSLT generate `<img src="~/Image/Cocktail.png">`? (2) Is `"~/Image/Cocktail.png"` a valid URL to use in HTML?

Comment: The first question should have been solved by ur solution provided above. The second question, actually i have no idea because i got that from a different solution provided by others in this website.

Comment: The first question should have been solved - but you're not saying if it was. I don't know the answer to the second question, and it has nothing to do with XSLT. If necessary, post a new question.